# How to remove the animated loader from hydralit (streamlit)?

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using Streamlit to build a web app and with [Hydralit](https://github.com/TangleSpace/hydralit) I was able to use the multipage function. However, the function came with an animated loader that I would like to remove.

What command can I use to remove it?

```
app = hy.HydraApp()


@app.addapp(title='Introdução', icon="")
def my_home():
    st.title("órbitas tipo-tempo para corpos massivos")

@app.addapp(title='Corpos massivos', icon="")
def app2():
    st.title("Simulador para cálculo das órbitas relativísticas de corpos com massa")
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like there is an open issue for a similar problem: https://github.com/TangleSpace/hydralit/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

```
import streamlit as st
from hydralit_components import HyLoader, Loaders
from hydralit.app_template import HydraHeadApp

class LoadingApp(HydraHeadApp):

def run(self,app_target):

    try:
        app_title = ''
        if hasattr(app_target,'title'):
            app_title = app_target.title

        # with HyLoader("Now loading {}".format(app_title), loader_name=Loaders.standard_loaders,index=[3,0,5]):
        app_target.run()
  
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydralit/loading_app.py

You have to change this line!

I finally found it.